# Mouseovers should be activated using keyboard?

Tags: keyboard

In [usability.gov's Research-Based Web Design and Usability Guides](http://www.usability.gov/sites/default/files/documents/guidelines_book.pdf) in section 3:7, "Ensure that Scripts Allow Accessibility" says：

> Whenever a script changes the content of a page, the change must be indicated in a way that
>   can be detected and read by a screen reader. Also, if 'mouseovers' are used, ensure that they can be activated using a keyboard.

I was just curious about what is the common behavior of activate the mouse-overs using keyboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browsers allow users to tab through links using the Tab key on the keyboard. As you move from link to link, the current link is said to have focus. It's similar to the onFocus and that should be treated as equivalent to mouseOver and this onFocus should be emulating whatever effect the mouseOver has

Comment: Sometimes, there are additional information appears with the mouseover(tooltips, navigation...). For example: website [link](http://www.usa.gov/index.shtml#home_main_content) , when mouseover the tabs (service, blog, topics...), there will be sub-navigations, i just don't see how to active them using keyboard:(  . From usability prospective, should or shouldn't considering about that? Thanks